# Testing React Component with Props & RouteComponentProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I have a React component:

```
export default class ItemDetails extends React.Component<Props & RouteComponentProps<{ id: string}>, State> {

    public constructor(props: Props & RouteComponentProps<{ id: string}>) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            item: {
                id: 0,
                price: '$0.00'
            }
        };
    }

    public async componentWillMount() {
        let item = await ItemService.fetch(Number(this.props.match.params.id));
        this.setState({item: item});
    };


    public render() {
        let {item} = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="itemDetails">
                <itemDetailsHeader item={item}/>
                <itemDetailsBody item={item}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

and am trying to test this component, such that, when the component renders, displays the data from the service call in the underlying components.

My test is throwing an error, stating it `Cannot read property 'params' of undefined`. This is on the `this.props.match.params.id` params. My test is shown below:

```
let mock: any = jest.fn();

var match: {
    isExact: true,
    params: { id: '1' },
    path: "",
    url: ""
}

jest.mock('../../../src/actions/apiHelper', () => {
    return {
        getItem: () => new Promise(resolve => resolve(
            {id: 1, price: '$9.99'}
        ))
    };
});


describe("Item Details", () => {

    describe("Header", () => {

        it('should display the price of the item', () => {
            const wrapper = mount(<ItemDetails match={match} location={mock} history={mock}/>);
            expect(wrapper.find(".itemDetails--price").text()).toEqual("$9.99");
        });
    })
});
```

How can I setup my ItemDetails component in the test, with the proper params for RouteComponentProps, to allow the fetch call to be stubbed out and not receive the error I am currently receiving for the props being undefined?

Comment: By looking at your code, it does not seem that the `ItemDetails` component should get `undefined` in your `match` props.

I see that you are using `mount` to test your component though. Is it possible that any of your `itemDetailsHeader` or `itemDetailsBody` components is also using `this.props.match`?

I would try using `shallow` instead of `mount` to test the `ItemDetails` component.

Comment: The props are only used at the top level component (ItemDetails)

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your error. Could you create a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) where your error is reproducible?